# What is $f(a,0)$ for $f(a,y) = \frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f(a,y) = \frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y}$

Why is $f(a,0) = b-a$. I don't even know how to try to get the function into a form to be "seen" that it is continuous at $y = 0$.

How to see that?

Comment: A reasonable statement of the problem were to define $f(a,0)$ s.t. the function $f(a,y)$ is continuous at $y=0$.

Comment: @user yes exaclty

Answer (score 3):

May be you were asked to find the limit of the function as $y\to 0$.

$$\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^{-ay} - e^{-by}}{y}=b\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^{-by} - 1}{-by}-a\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^{-ay} - 1}{-ay} = b-a$$

Answer (score 2):

The function is neither defined, nor continuous at $0$, due to the division by zero.

Perhaps what is being referenced is the fact that

$$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{e^{-ay} - e^{-by}}{y} = b-a$$

If you let

$$\widetilde{f}(a,y) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{e^{-ay} - e^{-by}}{y} & y \ne 0 \\
b-a & y = 0
\end{cases}$$

then $\widetilde{f}$ is continuous in $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Though there are already good answers, let me add some details.
For any $c$,

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{cx} - 1}{x}
= 
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ce^{cx}}{1}
=
c
$$
by L'Hospital's rule. Or you can get the result by seeing it as the derivative of the function $e^{cx}$ at $x = 0$.

$$
\frac{e^{-ay} - e^{-by}}{y}
=
\frac{e^{-ay} - 1 + 1 - e^{-by}}{y}
=
\frac{e^{-ay} - 1}{y} - \frac{e^{-by} - 1}{y}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-ay} - e^{-by}}{y}
=
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-ay} - 1}{y} - \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-by} - 1}{y}
=
-a - (-b)
=
b - a
$$
since each term is convergent.

The function you gave is not defined at $y = 0$. So you should define the value at the point. But I will take the limit as $y$ approaches $0$ as the value of the function. Then, by the definition of continuity, the function is continuous at $y = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y}$$

Use Taylor series expansion for $e^{-ay}$

$$e^{-ay}=1-ay+\frac{(ay)^2}{2}+O(y^3)$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y} \approx \frac{1-ay+\frac{(ay)^2}{2}-1+by-\frac{(by)^2}{2}}{y}=b-a$$

as required